# How to load dynamic option with ajax

Tags: ajax, theme-options, options, wp-localize-script

Basically I'm creating an options page in which the user will click on a button to display a text input field, which will then be populated by the user with a name.

This name will be then saved into the db using ajax (all that's working already). The user will be able to as many names she/he wants.

At the moment, as a feedback to the user, I'm adding a list with the names that were previously saved with jQuery, however I'd like to load the options from the db to check whether the info collected by jQuery is correct.

I've been doing some research and it seems the way to do it is to use `wp_localize_script` which I'm finding it cumbersome to load dynamically created data.

Is using `wp_localize_script` the correct way to do it or should I just make an ajax call as you'd normally do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is really a right answer to this question, and I don't know what you find cumbersome about `wp_localize_script`, but you should be able to do it either way.

The difference is that with `wp_localize_script` the data is printed to the source of the page, which you wouldn't want if the data were sensitive, and `wp_localize_script` should represent a wee bit less load on the server as it doesn't require a separate connection as AJAX does.

I'd lean towards `wp_localize_script` unless there are compelling reasons to do something else.

Comment: I find it cumbersome because in order to retrieve a relatively simple data I'll need to create a php function, use `add_action` and write some js as opposed to simple write some js and retrieve the data. This process will be repeated a few times. Both options have downsides: `the wp_localize_script` will pollute my application (I'll of course try to concatenate most of the functions together, but maybe not all) whilst creating multiple ajax calls will have a negative impact on performance. However this functionality is for WP admin area only, so won't be public facing.

Comment: Then take another look at [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). If your existing scripts are enqueued correctly then none of that should matter. You already have everything in place that you need and it is a matter of adding one or two lines of PHP.

Comment: "pollute" you application? What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear. I meant adding more code than necessary... I'll have another look at `wp_localize_script`. Maybe the example I've seen wasn't clear enough or I didn't really understand it. At least now I know that seems to be the best way anyway. Thanks for your help.